# Url carrega os caracteres !#%2F e não carrega a view correta em Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routes

Estou na minha raíz index.html e carrega normal, mas, quando digito o **#** mais a **/** e uma view por exemplo a view teste a url fica: **index.html#!#%2Fview-teste**. Gostaria de saber o pq!

Segue o código da rota:

```
angular.module('teste').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'], 
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
       $routeProvider

       .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'index.html',
         controller: 'testeCtrl'
       })
       .when('/teste', {
         templateUrl: 'view/teste.html',
         controller: 'testeCtrl'
     });                                                                  
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leandro, quando voce seta o html5Mode, você desabilita o uso do #, ou que chamamos de url amigável.

Para continuar usando o #, você tem que remover a linha `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. E para usar a url amigável, você precisa setar no head do index.html o `<base href="/">` e setar o `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

Abraços!

Comment: agora ta dando erro no console assim: **Error: $injector:modulerr**

Comment: pode ser que você esqueceu de colocar a referencia de algum arquivo ou modulo não ? como por exemplo ngRoute ....

Comment: @stringnome isto mesmo que ocorreu!